# Javascript button not working with function

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why this function is not working. Assignment instructions call for the javascript function code to be in it's own javascript file.

Here is the html

```
<h2>BMI Calculator</h2>

  <form>
     <input type="text" id="weight" value="0" />
     <label for="weight">Weight in pounds</label>
     <input type="text" id="height" value="0" />
     <label for="height">Height in inches</label>
     <input type="text" id="Result" value="0" />
     <label for="Result"> BMI Result </label>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate BMI" />
    </form>
```

Here is the function based on that form. It's supposed to calculate the bmi.

```
function calcBMI() {
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementByID("weight").value);
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementByID("height").value);
    var result = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
    var textbox = document.getElementById('Result').value;

    textbox.value = result;
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcBMI, false);
```

Comment: Define not working.

Comment: Show your error message

Comment: Your function must appear after define objects... place function just before </body> inside <script> your function </script>

Comment: Copy and pasted from assignment specifications...

create a function named calcBMI() that performs the calculation using the values in the weight and height text boxes and assign the result to the BMI text box.
Convert the value to an Integer number by using the parseInt() function.
Reference the text boxes from within the function by using the documentobject.getElementByID(name), and the value attribute of each text box (in other words, don’t use function arguments AKA pass values to the function).
Add an event listener to to call the calcBMI() function

Answer (score 3):

3 things:

1. `getElementById` must be in camel case. Not with capital D's at the end
2. Reference to textbox should be just `var textbox = document.getElementById('Result')` and not with `.value` at the end.
3. Button's type should be `button` otherwise the form is being posted.

Your working example:

```js
function calcBMI() {
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
    var result = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
    var textbox = document.getElementById('Result');
    textbox.value = result;
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcBMI, false);
```

```html
<h2>BMI Calculator</h2>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="weight" value="0" />
  <label for="weight">Weight in pounds</label>
  <input type="text" id="height" value="0" />
  <label for="height">Height in inches</label>
  <input type="text" id="Result" value="0" />
  <label for="Result"> BMI Result </label>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Calculate BMI" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

At a glance it seems as though you are not preventing the default browser behaviour, you need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the form submitting.

```
function [...](e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...]
}
```

### 2.

Ensure you `DOM` has loaded before manipulation begins by loading the JavaScript below the `HTML` or you can make use of the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

### 3.

A sanity check, ensure that the script has been loaded using the [`<script></script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tags. If it is an external file, use the `src` property, if it is just code, wrap it in the aforementioned tags.

### 4.

You need to change the usage of `getElementById` you have used `getElementByID` instead of the lowercase `d` in `Id`.

### 5.

When you are doing `textbox.value = result;` what you are actually doing is `textbox.value.value = result;` as you have referenced it as `.value` originally.

### *Finally,*

Make use of the console as it'll have saved you from asking here as the errors are thrown in them.

Comment: I'm totally new to this...how do I check errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Use on click event, change your getElementByID to getElementById and change the type to button and not submit. Submit would post it but what you need is to call the function.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Calculate BMI" onclick="calcBMI()"/>
```

In your javascript change

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('Result').value
```

To

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('Result').value = result;
```

And remove

```
textbox.value = result;
```

Comment: How would this fix the issue?

Comment: See my updated answer. The type 'submit' was posting the form and that is why the function is not running.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your function:

1. You have a typo in `document.getElementByID`, it should be `document.getElementById`
2. You have to pass an event object into your function, and invoke preventDefault, so that your form won't be submitted to the server
3. the line:

`var textbox = document.getElementById('Result').value;`

it should be

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('Result');
```

So overall, your function should look like:

```
function calcBMI(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
    var result = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
    var textbox = document.getElementById('Result');

    textbox.value = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does indeed work. however, based on the assignment instructions I do believe that code is above what we have gone over in class. 

Can you explain what the e.preventDefault(); does? I also noticed you passed an e....calcBMI(e)

What was that?

Comment: To clarify... 
Copy and pasted from assignment specifications... create a function named calcBMI() that performs the calculation using the values in the weight and height text boxes and assign the result to the BMI text box. Convert the value to an Integer number by using the parseInt() function. Reference the text boxes from within the function by using the documentobject.getElementByID(name), and the value attribute of each text box (in other words, don’t use function arguments AKA pass values to the function). Add an event listener to to call the calcBMI() function

Comment: e is a parameter passed by Javascript, it has type 'event' and contains information about the event that happened when you clicked the button 'submit'. PreventDefault is a method that prevent the default action of the button, which is in this case is to submit the form to the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on the instructions, was there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake here in weight and heightIt should be in camel case only. 
document.getElementById("your id")
and also why not you check in console  what error it shows